# Change the checkbox value using the radio button

Tags: javascript

If the user selects the category1 radio button, the value of the check boxes must be changed. And display them when the user checks the check box.

If the user selects the category 2 radio button, another set of values assign to the checkboxes.

If the user selects the category 3 radio button, another set of values must assign to the check boxes.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[id="radio1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', 5000);
    } else if ($('input[id="radio2"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', 10, 000);
    } else if ($('input[id="radio3"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', 25, 000);
    }
  });

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $("#output").show();

    if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      type1 = $('input[name="checkbox1"]').val()
      $("#output").html(type1);
    } else if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == false) {
      $("#output").hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="radio1">category1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2">category2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio3">category3<br/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">type1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">type2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">type3<br/>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the **[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Give it a try first.

Comment: You need to show at least a smidgin of effort if you expect an answer...

Comment: any one please help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your radio's the same name :

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="category">category1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="category">category2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="category">category3<br/>
```

Then you should wrap the value by quotes in the `attr()` assignment :

```
if ($('input[id="radio1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
    $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '5000');
} else if ($('input[id="radio2"]').prop("checked") == true) {
  $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '10,000');
    _________________________________________^______^
} else if ($('input[id="radio3"]').prop("checked") == true) {
  $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '25,000');
    _________________________________________^______^
}
```

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[id="radio1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '5000');
    } else if ($('input[id="radio2"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '10,000');
    } else if ($('input[id="radio3"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      $('input[name="checkbox1"]').attr('value', '25,000');
    }
  });

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $("#output").show();

    if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == true) {
      type1 = $('input[name="checkbox1"]').val()
      $("#output").html(type1);
    } else if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop("checked") == false) {
      $("#output").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="category">category1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="category">category2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="category">category3<br/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">type1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">type2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">type3<br/>
<span id="output"></span>
```